# use (void **) do swap function

Tags: c, pointers, void

Why don't values `int i` and `int j` in the main function swap?

In the swap function, I print `*a` and `*b` addresses. They point to `i` and `j` respectively, and I can see that addresses are changed.
I don't know why the main function `i` and `j` values are not changed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(void **a, void **b)
{
    printf("1swap a address = %d %p\n",*(int*)*a,*a);
    printf("1swap b address = %d %p\n",*(int*)*b,*b);
    void *t;
    t =*a;
    *a =*b;
    *b=t;
    printf("2swap a address = %d %p\n",*(int*)*a,*a);
    printf("2swap b address = %d %p\n",*(int*)*b,*b);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int j = 5;
    int *p = &i;
    int *q = &j;

    printf(" i address = %p\n",&i);
    printf(" j address = %p\n",&j);

    printf("-org i = %d , j = %d\n",i,j);
    swap((void **)&p, (void **)&q);
    printf("-mod i = %d , j = %d\n",i,j);

    printf(" i address = %p\n",&i);
    printf(" j address = %p\n",&j);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected `i` and `j` values would swap.

Comment: Why would `i` and `j` swap?  You're swapping `p` and `q`, not `*p` and `*q`.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap function swaps pointers `p` and `q`.

### Swap function for integers

If you want to swap `i` and `j`, you cannot use void (As the compiler wouldn't know what to dereference - `void` has no size). Also, no need for pointer to pointer (**), just pointer is sufficient.

```c
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
...
// then use this in main as
swap(&i, &j);
...
```

You would define a new swap function for each type you want to be swapping.

### General-type swap

*I don't recommend doing this. It introduces vulnerabilities for no significant gain.*

If you insist on `void` (f.e. you want to use the function for general type), you need to pass another parameter, which is the size of the type (As compiler don't know the type of your parameters). **Be careful though, this is going to be very error-prone**.

I'd recommend defining new `swap()` for each type you need, as stated before.

General swap would be defined like this:

```c
#define SWAP_STACK_MAX 256

void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    // Edit: malloc/free operations aren't as efficient as having the
    //       temporary variable defined on the stack.
    uint8_t stack_buffer[SWAP_STACK_MAX];
    void* t = stack_buffer;
    if (size > SWAP_STACK_MAX)
    {
        t = malloc(size);
        if (t == NULL)
            abort(); // Or handle somehow.
    }
    memcpy(t, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, t, size);
    free(t);
}
...
// then use this in main as
swap((void*)&i, (void*)&j, sizeof(i));
...
```

[small size optimization](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2019/10/27/).

Answer (score 0):

- This is a bug and invalid C: `(void **)&p`. You cannot convert a `int**` into a `void**`. The only pointer in C which has a special meaning and can be converted to any other pointer type is `void*`. That special rule does not apply "recursively" to `void**`. So your function parameters are wrong.
- It doesn't make much sense to swap too pointers with each other. If you do, the pointers `p` and `q` will get swapped indeed, but not what they point at. You *cannot* change the addresses of `i` and `j`. Addresses are assigned by the compiler/linker, never by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use double pointers:

```
void swapPointers(void *a, void *b)  
{  
    int *t;  
    int **ai = a;
    int **bi = b;
    t = *ai;  
    *ai = *bi;  
    *bi = t;  
}  

void swapValues(void *av, void *bv, size_t size)  
{  
    int **a = av;
    int **b = bv;
    char array[size];  
    memcpy(array, *a, size);  
    memcpy(*a, *b, size);  
    memcpy(*b, array, size);  
}  

int main()  
{  
    int i = 3;  
    int j = 5;  
    int *p = &i;  
    int *q = &j;  

    printf("Pointers\n");
    printf("-org *p = %d , *q = %d\n",*p,*q);
    swapPointers(&p, &q);  
    printf("-mod *p = %d , *q = %d\n", *p, *q);

    printf("Values\n");
    printf("-org i = %d , j = %d\n",i,j);
    swapValues(&p, &q, sizeof(*p));  
    printf("-mod i = %d , j = %d\n", i, j);
}
```